# "Rails is not currently installed" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i'm new to ruby on rails 
I have 3 ruby version in my computer.

In a project i had to use rails 3.2.1 and ruby 1.9.2
So I switched using rvm use 1.9.2 in terminal. But after that my rails commands are not detected.

```
$ rails g model abc
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

Why is this happening? And how to solve this?

Comment: Did you run `bundle`?

Comment: All of these answers suggest installing the rails gem, but @MarekLipka suggestion of using bundle is far more appropriate. Check your gemfile for a rails version, read some instructions on bundle usage at http://bundler.io/

Comment: Marek Lipka thanks, i forgot to run bundle install after i changed the ruby version. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to differentiate your gem set that contains that specific version of rails from the old ones.

```
rvm use 1.9.2@new_gem_set_of_yours --create --default
```

And then retry installing the 3.2.1 rails

```
gem install rails --version 3.2.1
```

Or specify the new rails version in your Gemfile and let Bundler take care of it

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
```

and run `bundle install`.

Comment: Don't install rails as a gem, use bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Type in your terminal

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.1
```

if it does not work, first try

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

then

```
rvm rubygems current
```

and repeat.

Comment: Don't install rails as a gem, use bundle.